# What on God's green earth are "pulley shoes"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, etymology, middle-english, sexual-minorities

I keep running into sources talking about [**pulley-shoes**](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=743gDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA196), [**pulley-toe shoes**](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=jc_CAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA112), [**pulley-toes**](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=bdB2DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA38), &c. even though they don't always play well with Google OCR and are basically invisible to vanilla searches.

Those extremely weird terms don't show up in any dictionary including the *OED* but it's clear they're talking about some kind of medieval shoe with pointed toes. [One source](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=MUNj-t9BMOoC&pg=PA279) even glosses the term with the French phrase *souliers à la poulaine* ("shoes in the Polish style").

Now, [poulaines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/poulaine) are properly the version of the pointy-toed shoe that spread across Europe in the mid-14th century and differed in some ways from [the "scorpion tail" shoes](https://archive.org/details/ecclesiasticalhi0006orde/page/66/mode/2up?q=pulley&view=theater) that [Orderic Vitalis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orderic_Vitalis) thought the [bunion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/bunion)-afflicted womanizer [Fulk of Anjou](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fulk_le_Rechin) was using to cover up his sinful deformity and from [the stuffed "ram's horn" shoes](https://archive.org/details/chibnall-orderic-vitalis-vol-4/page/188/mode/2up?view=theater) that Richard the Horny [was using to turn everyone gay](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=e6J0BgAAQBAJ&pg=PA82) in the late 11th century.

Thing is, though, I can't find any *period* sources talking about "pulley" footwear at all... not that Google is being helpful even with displaying even uses of the terms I've already found.

**Any idea where these bizarre and unhelpful names 'pulley shoe' and 'pulley toe' came from?** Are they [*just* variants of *poulaine* that the OED hasn't noticed yet](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/148984) and that are being misapplied to the wrong century out of historians' general unfamiliarity/distaste with fashion? or is there any more to it, like a passage in [William of Malmesbury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_of_Malmesbury) or something? (Complaining about the ridiculous clothes of 'the kids these days' and the excesses of the 1% was of course one of the favorite pastimes of monastic and ecclesiastical historians in any age.)

[image]

Comment: I suspect that the three links at the top are in Japanese. "Pulley shoes" show up on Google here as being shoes with wheels: like a hybrid between a rollerskate and a normal shoe. Perhaps a bit like a toy car you wear on your feet.

Comment: +1 for a well-posed question - quirky - but well posed.

Comment: Some of the tags you've chosen don't seem applicable to me, especially the "sexual-minorities" tag, which, with the exception of one brief mention in passing, seems to be entirely unrelated to this question.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan You can always change them, although if you actually read the passage in Orderic's history, it very much applies in spaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaades. He's literally Alex Jones-like blaming the surge in 11th century gayness on these shoes.

Comment: @Graffito Thank you for that although the weird _a_ in your post isn't quite right: _...the notorious 'pulley-shoes' of the twelfth century_ (9.3) _and later in the 'poulaines'... of the fourteenth_ (9.5)... So here at least they're using it __in direct contrast__ to poulaines. Can you see what figures 9.3 and 9.5 look like? or is there any later explanation of wtf 'pulley shoe' came from if not misapplication of poulaine?

Comment: @WeatherVane You can click them on the computer of your chosing. None of it is Japanese. You can also check Graffito's link. Some roller sneakers may show up in your Googling and many of these scholarly sources are basically invisible (as stated) but no this post is specifically talking about actual footwear named specifically "pulley shoes", "pulley toe shoes", &c. applied to medieval fashion.

Comment: It's a shame that the first FOUR links show up as empty pages, Google tells me "You have either reached a page that is unavailable for viewing or reached your viewing limit for this book" The other links work for me though.

Comment: I forgot to add  my location is in Italy. @WeatherVane Japanese words that appear on the left side refer to sites where the books can be purchased, e.g. Amazon.japan

Comment: @Mari-LouA Don't know what to tell you besides "use a VPN". The pages exist and are provided in some markets. One work around is sometimes to see what a quote from the page is via Google Books, search that exact quotation, and then click in from those links. Sometimes it also helps if you clear your cache or otherwise stop Google's servers from seeing what you've already read from a document. You're doing well enough living in Italy though. Skip the internet and just have some more table wine xD and it's not that bad of a life regardless.

Comment: I'm honestly more curious about what else Graffito's source has if you have any way of getting into Brill's system. You aren't missing much from the links I posted: they're just sources using the terms as mentioned, all for pointy-toed medieval shoes and not for roller sneakers.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Another lesser trick that you might sometimes find helpful is how (e.g.) I can follow my first link to page 196 of the book in question but it hides page 197, which finishes the passage. However, if you go to the URL bar, change the &pg=PA196 to &pg=PA197, and hit enter to reload the book to exactly that page, many times it will load the second half of the passage you're looking for while hiding the first part you've already read.

Comment: When I clicked a second time, all the excerpts were visible. Agreed, they're not essential reading and clearly these books were either written in the 20th or 21st century. I'm trying to determine their exact dates.

Comment: @Graffito Very clever guess but __(a)__ the pigaches that these scholars are calling pulley shoes weren't that long maxing out at about 2 inches past the toe except when illustrating the Antichrist (of course) and __(b)__ the chains-to-the-knees thing for the longer later poulaines seems to be a longstanding just-too-good-to-look-up urban myth. There's zero archaeological support and little to no period evidence for it last I saw, only a few guys centuries later who might possibly have had now-lost sources but more likely were just talking out their a*ses.

Comment: I’m not quite sure what your question is, but the Wikipedia article on *pigache* says the pigache (aka pigage, pulley shoe, pulley toe, or pulley-toe shoe) “is also simply glossed as a pointed-toe shoe and sometimes conflated with the later *poulaine*.” So they aren’t poulaines. Are you looking for the appearance of *pulley*, as regards to shoes,  prior to the 1500s?

Comment: Re: the LGBT association, [seems the Museum of London agrees](https://www.museumoflondon.org.uk/discover/lgbt-london-stories-pointy-shoes-and-sodomy). Re: Tinfoil, (a) I wrote that article and (b) there's a title and bolding to point out where the question is. Sorry it doesn't get clearer than that. No, Wiki and Google aren't going to answer this one or I already would've done that so if you don't have other resources, yeah, we'll just have to wait for some other people to help.

Comment: So, then, it seems that at some time after pigaches and poulaines were conflated, the term *pulley* emerged and got applied to both? There’s a word in the *OED* entry for *poulaines* that looks an awful lot like *pulley*: **1530   J. PALSGRAVE *Lesclarcissement* 259/1   Pullayne, *poullane.***

Comment: The earth is blue.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Ain't.

Comment: I have some sympathy, given the Welsh flag, but 'tis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The earliest mention of the term "pulley shoes" that a Google Books search turns up is from an explanatory footnote in Thomas Forester's 1854 translation of Ordericus Vitalis, [*The Ecclesiastical History of England and Normandy*](https://books.google.com/books?id=vWYRbLyNwoYC&pg=PA477&dq=%22pulley-shoes%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi2oZbph4uAAxXYJUQIHXrqDFYQ6AF6BAgIEAI#v=onepage&q=%22pulley-shoes%22&f=false), volume 2 [Book 8, Chapter 10] (original text published in Latin by the year 1143). Here is Forester's translated text from Ordericus Vitalis that prompts the footnote:

> This count [Fulk of Anjou, circa 1090] was very blameable, and even infamous in many parts of his conduct, and abandoned himself to all sorts of vices. His feet being deformed, he had shoes made of an unusual length, and very sharp at the toes, so that they might conceal the excrescences, commonly called bunnions, which caused his feet to be so ill-shaped. This new fashion became common throughout the west, and wonderfully pleased light-minded persons, and the lovers of novelty. In consequence, the shoemakers, in making shoes, shape them like scorpions' tails, vulgarly called pigaces,<sup>1</sup> a fashion which almost all the world, both rich and poor, are wonderfully taken with, while in former times, shoes with round toes, fitted to the form, were in common use both by rich and poor, clergy and laity. But now men of the world sought in their pride fashions of dress which accorded with their perverse habits ; and what formerly honourable persons thought a mark of disgrace, and rejected as infamous, the men of this age find to be sweet as honey to their taste, and parade on their persons as a special distinction.

And here is the footnote itself from Forester, published in 1854:

> <sup>1</sup> *Pigaceas ;* Ordericus appears to have Latinized a Norman-French term of the day, not now to be found in any vocabulary. The curious account of the fashions of the age supplied by our author shows that nothing escaped his observation, recluse as he was. That of the long-peaked shoes, with the toes trussed and fastened upwards, *souliers à la poulaine*, **pulley shoes**, as the French called them, flourished for three centuries, and was not given up till it was severely denounced by kings and popes.

So, according to Forester, Ordericus Vitalus created *pigaceas* as a learned neologism, a quasi-Latin form of "a Norman-French term of the day, not now to be found in any vocabulary." Forester then explicitly equates this style of shoe with the shoe identified by the contemporaneous (in the 1140s) French term *souliers à la poulaine*, which Forester translates as "pulley shoes." Presumably the "pulley" aspect of the expression derives from the trussing and fastening upwards of the Pinocchio toes on shoes of this type, the better to permit actual walking and even running.

As a side note, I must say that I find it strangely comforting that Western culture didn't begin its descent into decadence until the very late eleventh century, according to Ordericus Vitalus, before which time honorable people wore sensible shoes and censured fashions of dress that accorded with their wearers' perverse habits. With what nostalgic regret his readers must have thought back to the Golden Age of circa 1080, when Ordericus Vitalus was but an innocent lad and society hadn't yet gone to pot.

Comment: [See my last comment on Ms A's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/609946/171986) about a possible (probable?) alternate derivation for 'pulley' in this context but __(a)__ you're not wrong that even if modern scholars are dubious that anyone ever actually tied up their poulaines the 19th century believed people had and __(b)__ this is extremely likely the source of learned reuse of this bizarrely unhelpful modern term in the 20th and 21st century. I'd imagine most historians of the age would've read this translation of that work at some point in their training on the era.

Comment: As an aside, your last paragraph is delightful. Glad to have shared a little sunshine with this quirky adventure into medieval fashionistas.

Answer (score 2):

*Souliers à la poulaine*, *Poulaines*, [pykes](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED33324) <sup>1</sup>, [*pigache*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigache) <sup>2</sup>, *Krakowes*, and *Crakows* were all names for those peculiar elongated pointy shoes that were in fashion between the twelfth and fifteenth century in Europe. In Italy they were called *[Cracovia](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mWZo64EUUG0&t=1692shttps://)* <sup>3</sup> <sup><sub>*link:YouTube*</sub></sup>  or *scarpe polacchi* (Polish shoes). As to when the English called them *pulley-toes* and *pulley-shoes* I have yet to determine.

> The pigache is also known as the **pigage**, **pulley shoe**,
> <sup>[[7]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigache#cite_note-aird-7)</sup> <sup>[[8]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigache#cite_note-FOOTNOTECoatsworth_&_al.2018349-8)</sup> **pulley toe**,<sup>[[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigache#cite_note-ruby-1)</sup> or **pulley-toe shoe**.<sup>[[9]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigache#cite_note-FOOTNOTEYarrow2011%5Bhttpsbooksgooglecojpbooksidjc_CAwAAQBAJpgPA112_112%5D-9)</sup> Less often, Orderic Vitalis's terms of opprobrium are reworked into names: **scorpion's tail** or **ram's horn shoe**.  *[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigache#Names)*

As this footwear became highly desirable among courtiers, the nobility, and subsequently by the bourgeoise, the original French name *[souliers à la poulaine](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/poulaine#Etymology_2)* <sup>4</sup>, meaning shoes in the Polish style; derived from the Old French term for Poland, [*Poulaine*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/poulaine) <sup>5</sup>, was adopted by Anglo-Norman speakers during the medieval period.

> **Anglo-Norman language**
> …from the late 12th century to the early 15th century, **Anglo-French** was much used in law reports, charters, ordinances, official correspondence, and trade at all levels; they were **the language of the King, his court and the upper class.** *[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglo-Norman_language)*

---

Sources:

1. Middle English Dictionary entry for Pike, definition
2. *Wikipedia*
3. *Chopine e Poulaine: calzature di Moda dal Medioevo all'Età Moderna*
   An Italian ‘magazine’ written and presented by YouTuber Matteo Rubboli.
4. Wiktionary (etymology)
5. Etymonline

Comment: I'll have to come back to this later.

Comment: They were also called [pikes](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED33324) for obvious reasons.

Comment: Again, those terms all seem to come in the 14th century in reference to other shoes (introduced to England by the retinue of Anne of Bohemia) entirely distinct from the ones Orderic was complaining about and which the later historians were calling pulley shoes and (as shown above) distinguishing from the longer later poulaines.

Comment: Yes, there are 'similar' pointed shoes attested in statuary going back to at least the 3rd millennium BC around Elam. No, I wasn't asking about those either. Sorry if the illustration mislead you, although there are a few manuscripts that overdo the pigaches to the point they ended up looking like the later poulaines.

Comment: @Laurel  Since when do "we" have to attribute ***links***? Excerpts, yes. Quotes, yes. But links?  I mean, imagine giving the title of every book that Ily provides a link to. It would look a real mess. (I see from the edit history that the editor, E. Ashworth sensibly refrained).   Moreover, I don't like the aesthetics, the answer looks crowded and the links should be on the terms not the sources.  I don't have time to sort this out, or to find a compromise, but I'm very disappointed by the (ugly and unwarranted) editing. Unless you can point me where it has become official policy.

Comment: @Ily I believe that the names; *pulley-shoes*, *pulley-toe*,  and *pulley-toes*  shoes are ***probably variants***, or the ***Anglicized versions*** of *poulaines* but I haven't got any hard facts... not yet. Maybe I will tonight or tomorrow. In the meantime, I'm looking forward to seeing Sven Yargs' answer! (Bound to post something.)

Comment: There's no rule that you have to attribute links (got into the same argument myself elsewhere). However, it may be helpful for the less technically savvy (who don't know how to see the URL without clicking on it). A more elegant solution (or compromise?) would be in-text (e.g., "according to Etymonline…").

Comment: https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED10181

Comment: For what it's worth, this answer will need that coming back to but I __completely__ agree with Ms A that the editing is an eyesore. I had assumed she was doing it for clarity (fine) but if you or other editors are forcing it on people, jeez, just stop. If people don't know how to see the URL without clicking on it... they can click on it. How could that possibly be a problem?

Comment: See also OED under **pole**, sb. 4: Poland; variant spellings from the 16th century **poyle** and **poole** would have been disyllabic and could have ultimately led to later **pulley-shoes** with the meaning "Poland-shoes".

Comment: @Ily: was your comment directed to me?  I haven't touched the answer, only added the two comments above.

Comment: @Tim Alternatively, it's possible that it's the other way around: all the way back in Middle English [pulley looked like polein, poleyn, poulain, &c.](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED33909) Thing is, though, I don't see any of those being used for the shoes... it's a modern thing afaict which is what's so stupifying about why someone would go out of their way _now_ to create such a useless misunderstanding... and then go out of their way to apply it to the wrong shoe. It should _have_ to come from _some_ earlier source, right?

Comment: The handling of links in this answer is now the subject matter of a [meta-question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15642/).